# Quantum mechanical interpretation for the (odd?) fact that a strained metal wire increases its volume

Tags: thermodynamics

If a short nickel wire is strained within the range of validity of Hooke’s Law, its volume increases by
 0.02 mm$^3$.

*Paradoxically, Göritz* (p. 194) says that for entropy elasticity, volume consistency has always been presupposed*.

Göritz doesn’t say anything about a temperature effect, but according to Le Chatelier’s Principle, of course, cooling is to be expected.

My question is, how this cooling would be explained with theoretical physics (quantum statistics). − But it is entangled by the additional question whether the volume increase plays any crucial role, which is confusing since I previously never heard of such an increase.

---

*) D. Göritz, Messung der Volumenänderung beim uniaxialen Dehnen, [*Colloid Polym. Sci.* **260**, p. 193 (1982)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01465439). − He does not say anything, how long this wire was, but from fig. 1 in the article, I would estimate it at 7 cm.

Comment: Exactly what strain is applied to achieve this increase in volume?

Comment: @Symmetry: The German title says (I translate): "Measurment of the volume change upon **uniaxial extension**". −  There are both a German and an English abstract.  In the German abstract, he says "uniaxiale Dehnung"; and in the English abstract, he writes only "volume change during extension".

Comment: If the wire is extended along the long axis, what fact do you find odd? Is that that the volume increases (rather than decreases) or that the observed value is not the one predicted? The absolute change in volume is not relevant until you know the dimensions of the wire and the tension applied.

Comment: @nasu: My problem was, that I had the idea that the volume increase would itself lead to cooling, because the electrons expand and perform work against the metal lattice. - This idea confused and fascinated me, and I forgot a bit that there is anyway cooling because of the entropy change by the tension of the metal lattice. -- It is strange that in the paper there is no clear statement of the dimensions of the wire; the tensil strain applied is 50 MPa.

Comment: OK, now is clear. From the title it would seem that the odd thing is the volume increase rather than the effect of the increase on the temperature.

Comment: @nasu: You say: "...increase on the temperature."?? -- I thought that the temperature decreases.

If the temperature of the wire decreases (when it is extended), then one would think that the entropy decreases too, since this destabilisation absorbs energy (which hence explains the lowering of the temperature).

Comment: @nasu: The volume increase has two aspects:

**1.** The voluminal (or statistical) entropy increases --> raising  of the temperature of the rod. −
**2.** The electrons perfom (so I suppose) work against the expanding borders of the metal --> cooling of the rod. −

**The question is:** Do 1 + 2 exactly compensate, as in the case of the ideal gas of molecules?

Answer (score 0):

One way to understand the cooling effect from a thermodynamic perspective is to recall that reversible work adds no entropy.

As you noted, uniaxial tensile loading of a solid increases its volume to some degree (because all solids have a Poisson's ratio of less than 0.5; therefore, lateral contraction never entirely offsets axial elongation, as it would in a liquid). The increase in volume increases the entropic configuration of the constitutive molecules (assuming that the solid is a typical ceramic, metal, or crosslinked polymer, *not* an elastomer, which I'll discuss later). But if the deformation occurs adiabatically (i.e., sufficiently insulated from the environment) and reversibly (i.e., at the unreachable limit of gradual loading), then the process is isentropic; no entropy is added or generated.

Therefore, the entropy associated with the increased freedom of the molecules comes from the solid's temperature itself, and cooling occurs.

If easy heat transfer to the environment is allowed, then the solid stays at ambient temperature. Interestingly, in this case, it is also somewhat more compliant, representing the difference between stretching it at constant entropy or at constant temperature.

If the loading is not reversible (e.g., it is performed quickly), then the temperature might decrease, stay the same, or increase, depend on the magnitude of dissipative processes such as vibrations or shock waves that generate entropy and thus heat the object.

For an elastomer, the situation is different; uniaxial loading uncoils and unkinks long unorganized polymers, which *decreases* their entropy. For an ideal elastomer, stiffness is entirely entropy-based, not enthalpy-based as it generally is in metals and ceramics. Again, for an adiabatic process, the entropy has nowhere to go except to increase the material's temperature. For such a material, the temperature coefficient of thermal expansion is negative.

As you noted, Le Chatelier's Principle can indicate the direction of temperature change, but only under the condition of reversibility, and one must know the sign of the temperature coefficient of thermal expansion. So the formulation in terms of the entropy of the constitutive molecules is more general.